# How to get a single character without pressing Enter in Elixir?

Tags: io, elixir

Similar with Ruby's `STDIN#getch`.

Elixir's `IO.gets/2` needs to press enter to get the character. Is there a way to get a single character without pressing Enter in Elixir?

Comment: There is an Elixir Sips episode that covers this http://elixirsips.com/episodes/192_interesting_io_part_2_input_with_tty_sl.html. Unfortunately it is subscriber only. All elixir code I can find that does this seems to use this magic ` Port.open({:spawn, "tty_sl -c -e"}, [:binary, :eof])`

Comment: iex(1)> Port.open({:spawn, "tty_sl -c -e"}, [:binary, :eof])
** (ErlangError) erlang error: :einval
    :erlang.open_port({:spawn, "tty_sl -c -e"}, [:binary, :eof])

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I try implementing non-trivial interactions with stdio in pretty much any language, ncurses pops up. So I'd take a look at this NIF https://github.com/jfreeze/ex_ncurses